# How can I implement a dropdown list in my Django form?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement a drop-down list in Django which contains the email addresses of those users whose domain matches to that of the currently logged in user.

I am using the following code but it still shows a list and not a drop down list. I tried changing the widget part from ChoiceField to MultipleChoiceField and now to CheckboxSelectMultiple just to see if checkbox is displayed or not but none of it seems to work.

Here is my **forms.py**

```
class AssignTask(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    assign_to = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=[], widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        user_email = self.user.email.split('@')[1]
        super(AssignTask, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['assign_to'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=[(i.email, i.email) for i in User.objects.filter(is_active=True, email__icontains=user_email)])
```

Here is my **views.py**

```
@login_required
def assigntask(request):
    assign_form = AssignTask(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'todoapp/assign_task.html', context={'assign': assign_form})
```

Here is my **html**

```
{% extends 'todoapp/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Create a task{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Create a task and assign it to a user</h2>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ assign.as_p }}
        <br/><input type="submit" value="Assign">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<button onclick="location.href='{%url 'dashboard' %}'" type="button">Go back</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**Apparently this solution works for me**

```
class AssignTask(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    assign_to = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(choices=[]))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        user_email = self.user.email.split('@')[1]
        super(AssignTask, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['assign_to'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(i.email, i.email) for i in User.objects.filter(is_active=True, email__icontains=user_email)])
```

Comment: What do you mean it shows a list?

Comment: A list as in a column sort of field with email-ids that are selectable

Comment: what different between your solution and the solution by @Exprator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, can this code be the solution?

forms.py

```
class AssignTask(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    # assign_to = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=[], widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        user_email = self.user.email.split('@')[1]
        super(AssignTask, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # self.fields['assign_to'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=[(i.email, i.email) for i in User.objects.filter(is_active=True, email__icontains=user_email)])
        self.fields['assign_to'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(i.email, i.email) for i in User.objects.filter(is_active=True, email__icontains=user_email)])
```

Can you see a dropdown box? And is this what you mean?

I guess you probably forgot to change inside the `__init__` function.

↓Added-----

What is important is inside the `__init__`.
The "assign_to" you declared first will be overwritten inside the `__init__` section.
For example, assuming that you declared "assign_to" as URLField, it will be overwritten by ChoiceField. What I am explaining is the below

forms.py

```
class AssignTask(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    assign_to = forms.URLField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        user_email = self.user.email.split('@')[1]
        super(AssignTask, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(self.fields)
        self.fields['assign_to'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(i.email, i.email) for i in User.objects.filter(is_active=True, email__icontains=user_email)])
        print(self.fields)
```

Output

```
OrderedDict([('title', <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x0000000004D90C88>), ('description', <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x0000000004D90CC0>), ('assign_to', <django.forms.fields.URLField object at 0x0000000004D90668>)])
OrderedDict([('title', <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x0000000004D90C88>), ('description', <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x0000000004D90CC0>), ('assign_to', <django.forms.fields.ChoiceField object at 0x0000000004D906A0>)])
```

and a dropdown box is still displayed, isn't it?

Comment: I have added a working solution for me. Check out the edited question

Comment: Yes, it works.
What is important is inside the __init__. 
I added the reason, please check it.

Comment: Good, any other problems?

Comment: No nothing as of now. Thanks a lot for the help ! :)